# C# The requested resource does not support http method patch

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I am working on PATCH method of my controller but I am constantly receiving error

> The requested resource does not support http method patch

RouteConfig.cs

```
// GET http://localhost:28888/v1/panels/
// PATCH http://localhost:28888/v1/panels/1

routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Panel",
    routeTemplate: "v1/panels/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Panel",
        id = RouteParameter.Optional,
    },
    constraints: null,
    handler: handler
);
```

PanelController.cs

```
[HttpPatch]
public HttpResponseMessage Patch(int panelId)
{
    if (panelId <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(panelId), "Can't be less or equal 0.");
    }

    panelTasks.SetPanelModified(panelId);

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

The Patch method is actually allowed. In Global.asax are below lines of codes

```
Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS");
Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

I am testing the url from Postman. The url is `localhost:28888/v1/panels/2902901`

Comment: Which version of WebApi are you using?  Are you using legacy .net or .net core?

Comment: legacy .net. still using System.Web

Comment: If you want it to map your route correctly automatically, the parameter names need to match.  It won't automatically map `id` to `panelId`

Comment: @stephen.vakil it was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@stephen.vakil

> If you want it to map your route correctly automatically, the
>   parameter names need to match. It won't automatically map `id` to
>   `panelId`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IIS? If so, try to remove the WebDav map:

1. Open IIS and go to the site in question.
2. Click on "Handler Mappings"
3. Find the handler named "WebDAV"
4. Remove it

Answer (score 0):

web.config on web api side configure allowed methods in sections httpProtocol,

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE" />
```

Is not there some conflict (with settings in code) or missing setting?